# Drone camera view frustum

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to derive formula (2) from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330591594_Perspective_Correcting_Visual_Odometry_for_Agile_MAVs_using_a_Pixel_Processor_Array). Formula describes the size of an area seen from UAV camera:
[image: camera view frustum]

Length $W$ is given in the paper as $D\frac{\sin(α)}{cos(θ)cos(α)}$. Camera view $α$ is same in both directions. How one arrives at this formula?

My reasoning is as follows:

(1) Altitude of an isosceles triangle with the base $W$ and the top point is $h = \frac{D}{\cos(θ)}$

(2) Base of isosceles triangle is $W = 2  h  \tan(α/2)$.

(1) and (2) combined: $W = 2D\frac{\tan(α/2)}{\cos(θ)} \ or \ 2D\frac{\sin(α/2)} { cos(θ)cos(α/2)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article states that

> Let $\theta$ denote the sensors angle of deviation from being orientated normal to the ground plane, and $\alpha$ denote the sensors field of view.

The coordinate system origin is at the image sensor focal point, with ground at $z = D \gt 0$.  Let's choose the $x$ and $y$ axes so that $W$ is measured along the $x$ axis, and $H$ is measured along the $y$ axis, both on the $z = D$ plane.  Then, $\alpha_W$ is a rotation around the $y$ axis, and $\alpha_L$ and $\theta$ are a rotation around the $x$ axis, in this order. Since the ray direction for $\alpha_W = \alpha_L = \theta = 0$ is $(0, 0, 1)$ (normal to the ground plane, towards the ground plane), we can construct the unit direction view ray vector as
$$\mathbf{r}\left(\alpha_W, \alpha_L, \theta\right) = \left [ \begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos\left(\alpha_L + \theta\right) & \sin\left(\alpha_L + \theta\right) \\
0 & -\sin\left(\alpha_L + \theta\right) & \cos\left(\alpha_L + \theta\right) \\
\end{matrix} \right ] \left [ \begin{matrix}
\cos\left(\alpha_W\right) & 0 & \sin\left(\alpha_W\right) \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-\sin\left(\alpha_W\right) & 0 & \cos\left(\alpha_W\right) \\
\end{matrix} \right ] \left[ \begin{matrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\
\end{matrix} \right ]$$
i.e. as
$$\mathbf{r}\left(\alpha_W, \alpha_L, \theta\right) = \Bigr( \sin(\alpha_W), ~ \cos(\alpha_W) \sin(\alpha_L + \theta), ~ \cos(\alpha_W) \cos(\alpha_L + \theta) \Bigr)$$
It is interesting to note that this intersects the $z = D$ plane at
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{p}\left(\alpha_W, \alpha_L, \theta\right) &= \left( \frac{D \sin(\alpha_W)}{\cos(\alpha_W)\cos(\alpha_L + \theta)}, ~ \frac{D \sin(\alpha_L + \theta)}{\cos(\alpha_L + \theta)}, ~ D \right) \\
~ &= \left( D \frac{\tan(\alpha_W)}{\cos(\alpha_L+\theta)}, ~ D \tan(\alpha_L + \theta), ~ D\right) \\
~ &= D \left( \frac{\tan(\alpha_W)}{\cos(\alpha_L+\theta)}, ~ \tan(\alpha_L + \theta), ~ 1\right) \\
\end{aligned}$$
The last form can be very useful for raycasting and locating the sampling points for each pixel. (Note that they are not uniform in $\alpha_W$ and $\alpha_L$, but form a regular rectangular grid in the the projection plane, which is perpendicular to $\mathbf{r}(0, 0, \theta) = (0, \sin\theta, \cos\theta)$.)

The midpoints of the edges of the outer faces of the view pyramid intersect ground, the $z = D$ plane, at
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{p}_{W+} &= \left( \frac{ D \tan(\alpha/2)}{\cos(\theta)}, ~ D \tan(\theta), ~ D \right) \\
\mathbf{p}_{W-} &= \left( \frac{-D \tan(\alpha/2)}{\cos(\theta)}, ~ D \tan(\theta), ~ D \right) \\
\mathbf{p}_{L+} &= \left( 0, ~ D \tan(\theta + \alpha/2), ~ D \right) \\
\mathbf{p}_{L-} &= \left( 0, ~ D \tan(\theta - \alpha/2), ~ D \right) \\
\end{aligned}$$
and $W$ and $L$ are defined as
$$\begin{aligned}
W &= \left[ \mathbf{p}_{W+} - \mathbf{p}_{W-} \right]_x \\
L &= \left[ \mathbf{p}_{L+} - \mathbf{p}_{L-} \right]_y \\
\end{aligned}$$
and indeed, out pop
$$\begin{aligned}
W &= \displaystyle 2 D \frac{\tan(\alpha/2)}{\cos\theta} \\
L &= \displaystyle D \tan\left(\theta + \alpha/2\right) - D \tan\left(\theta - \alpha/2\right) \\
\end{aligned}$$
I do not immediately see any way to reconcile the formulae in the paper with the description of the variables.

Note that the edges of the view pyramid intersect the $z = D$ plane (display corner coordinates in 3D) are
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{p}_{++} &= \left(  D \frac{\tan(\alpha/2)}{\cos(\theta+\alpha/2)}, ~ D \tan(\theta+\alpha/2), ~ D \right) \\
\mathbf{p}_{+-} &= \left( -D \frac{\tan(\alpha/2)}{\cos(\theta+\alpha/2)}, ~ D \tan(\theta+\alpha/2), ~ D \right) \\
\mathbf{p}_{-+} &= \left(  D \frac{\tan(\alpha/2)}{\cos(\theta-\alpha/2)}, ~ D \tan(\theta-\alpha/2), ~ D \right) \\
\mathbf{p}_{--} &= \left( -D \frac{\tan(\alpha/2)}{\cos(\theta-\alpha/2)}, ~ D \tan(\theta-\alpha/2), ~ D \right) \\
\end{aligned}$$

---

One way to define the projection plane is by its distance $d$ from origin.  The projection plane unit axis vectors $\hat{u}$ and $\hat{v}$ are (using the very first equation in this post, for vectors $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ so they are perpendicular to $\mathbf{r}(0, 0, \theta)$)
$$\begin{aligned}
\hat{u} &= \left( 1, ~ 0, ~ 0 \right) \\
\hat{v} &= \left( 0, ~ \cos(\theta), ~ -\sin(\theta) \right) \\
\end{aligned}$$
and point $\mathbf{P}(u, v)$ on the projection plane is at 3D coordinates
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{P}(u, v) &= d \mathbf{r}(0, 0, \theta) + u \hat{u} + v \hat{v} \\
~ &= \left( u ,~ d \sin(\theta) + v \cos(\theta) ,~ d \cos(\theta) - v \sin(\theta) \right) \\
\end{aligned}$$
This reaches the ground $z = D$ at
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{p}(u,v) &= \frac{D}{\left[\mathbf{P}(u,v)\right]_z} \mathbf{P}(u,v) \\
~&= \frac{D}{d \cos(\theta) - v\sin(\theta)} \mathbf{P}(u,v) \\
~&= \left( \frac{D u}{d \cos(\theta) - v\sin(\theta)} ,~ \frac{ D \bigr( d \sin(\theta) + v \cos(\theta) \bigr) }{d \cos(\theta) - v\sin(\theta)} ,~ D \right) \\
\end{aligned}$$
The view angles $\alpha_W$ and $\alpha_L$ depend on the projection plane distance $d$ and the range of coordinates $(u, v)$ on the projection plane.

This is much more important vector-valued function than the one in the article, because it combines the ground distance $D$, the deviation from ground normal $\theta$, projection plane coordinates $u$ and $v$, and the projection plane distance from eye $d$, to get the real world coordinates $x$, $y$, and $z = D$.

In particular, we can write it as
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x(u,v,z) &= \displaystyle \frac{z u}{d \cos(\theta) - v\sin(\theta)} \\
y(u,v,z) &= \displaystyle \frac{ z \bigr( d \sin(\theta) + v \cos(\theta) \bigr) }{d \cos(\theta) - v\sin(\theta)} \\
\end{aligned} \right .$$
in which case the inverse mapping is
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
u(x,y,z) &= \displaystyle \frac{d x}{z \cos(\theta) + y \sin(\theta)} \\
v(x,y,z) &= \displaystyle \frac{d \bigr(y \cos(\theta) - z \sin(\theta) \bigr)}{z \cos(\theta) + y \sin(\theta)} \\
\end{aligned} \right .$$
noting that for each image $d$, $\cos\theta$, $\sin\theta$, and $z$ are constants.
In other words, for exact sampling,
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
u(x, y) &= \displaystyle \frac{ C_1 x }{ C_2 + C_3 y } \\
v(x, y) &= \displaystyle \frac{ C_4 + C_5 y }{ C_2 + C_3 y } \\
\end{aligned} \right .$$
with the five constants calculated only once per image.  If the image is reconstructed row by row, then $u(x) = C_6 x$  with $C_6 = C_1 / (C_2 + C_3 y)$ calculated once for each $y$, with $v$ constant for any given $y$.

Alternatively, moving from $(x, y)$ to $(x+\Delta, y)$ only affects $u$, increasing it by $d \Delta / (z \cos(\theta) + y \sin(\theta))$, which is a constant for given $y$, $z$, $d$, $\theta$, and $\Delta$.

($(x, y)$ corresponds to compensated image coordinates, and $(u, v)$ to the sensor image coordinates.)

If you have enough memory for both the sensor 256×256 image and a separate compensated image buffer, this mapping should be easy to e.g. supersample  on a microcontroller core or an FPGA.

Comment: This is amazing answer! Kudos times 10E6